Extract conversation history in DialogFlow request
I'm having trouble retrieving the requests and responses from a chatbot I've created in Dialogflow using the Cloud Logging REST API. The thing is, I can see the name of the log, which is dialogflow_agent, but I don't see anything else when I try to make this request:
`GET https://logging.googleapis.com/v2/projects/voteugr/logs/
Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN
Content-Type: application/json`

Upon performing this request, I'm not receiving an error, but instead, I'm getting this:
`{
  "logNames": [
    "projects/voteugr/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity",
    "projects/voteugr/logs/dialogflow_agent"
  ]
}`

But if I try to access the specific case of dialogflow_agent, it returns a 404 error. How do I get a JSON with the logs, which are being stored in Cloud Logging? (I can download them manually, but I'd like to do it through a REST API to automate everything)

That is not the correct endpoint to retrieve log entries.
The GET https://logging.googleapis.com/v2/projects/YOUR_PROJECT_ID/logs/ is used to retrieve the list of names of logs, not the individual log entries themselves.
To retrieve the log entries, you should use the entries:list method
Which is POST https://logging.googleapis.com/v2/entries:list.
curl "https://logging.googleapis.com/v2/entries:list" \
  -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN" -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d'
  {
    "projectIds": [
      "voteugr"
    ],
    "filter":"logName=\"projects/voteugr/logs/dialogflow_agent\"",
    "pageSize": 100,
    "orderBy": "timestamp desc"
  }'

This will return a list of log entries in a JSON format.
"filter" part in the request body is used to query specific logs
To learn more about it see the next documentation:
https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/entries/list
